# Unable to debug Junit5 tests on intelliJ older to 2016.2

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

**Q1. Is there any plugin that can provide assistance to debug tests based out of Junit5 on intelliJ IDEA 2015.x?**

I've gone through articles over the Internet including [Running tests for JUnit5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests) and using [Junit5 in intelliJ IDEA](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea/) which agreed reads out -

> IntelliJ IDEA supports running tests on the JUnit Platform since
>   version 2016.2.

Present scenario -

1. Projects framed on Maven using JUnit5
2. Our team has people working on the different version of IntelliJ.
3. People with older version of intelliJ are able to execute the tests(`mvn test`) but not debug these using the intelliJ.

**Q2. Does this imply upgrading to 2016.2+ in order to contribute to projects using Junit5?**

Comment: JUnit 5 has been changing a lot recently and is still not released at this moment. IntelliJ IDEA was updated as well to support the changes in JUnit 5, the proper support for JUnit 5 M4 is available in 2017.1.3 version.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Do you mean we should wait to implement junit-jupiter in tests unless there is a RELEASE for the same?

Comment: You can use M4 if you like with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3, or you can wait until the final version is released. It's up to you.

Comment: Just to confirm *...and the debugging support would then be available for the older version of intelliJ as well.* @CrazyCoder Is it?

Comment: Older versions of IntelliJ IDEA will not be able to run/debug JUnit 5, most likely.

Comment: That's what I eventually thought to ask Q2. Is there an official confirmation on the same as well?

Comment: Initial support of JUnit 5 is available since 2016.2 version, but because of the recent incompatible changes in JUnit M4 you will need the current IntelliJ IDEA version for proper support. So, either stay on JUnit 4 or update to the current IDE and JUnit versions, simple as that.